# Replace a regex pattern in a string with a replacement string dependant on the match

Tags: java, javascript, python, regex

I have a special string which contains variables. Any word that begins with an "@" symbol is a variable in this string.

Example *foostring*:

> This is my string and this is a @variable in it.  Example, @hello is
>   another variable

I want to carry out an operation that replaces any general variable **@-variable-** in such special strings with **%-variable-%**.

So the Example *foostring* string above will become so (after this operation):

> This is my string and this is a %variable% in it.  Example, %hello% is
>   another variable

Question:
How to carry out this operation using Regular expressions?

Comment: Which language are you implementing this in? You've tagged Java, Javascript & Python!

Comment: I am implementing it in Javascript. Since its a general question (language independent) it would be good to have solutions in multiple languages for the benefit of different readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Javascript:

```
var repl = str.replace(/@(\w+)/g, '%$1%');
```

In Java:

```
String repl = str.replaceAll("@(\\w+)", "%$1%");
```

In python, for completeness' sake

```
import re
repl = re.sub(r'@(\w+)', r'%\1%', strng)
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know we have a way to access matched parameters when replacing with regex. Thanks for the interesting solution @anubhava; and for python solution too, @thg435